# How to do @layer more specific or ignore specifity? Angular, css

Tags: css, angular, primeng

About a month ago, I updated PrimeNG in my Angular application. I didn't pay attention to whether it was the new version of PrimeNG or the release of the new Chrome version from October 30. The issue is that the @layer started making changes to my styles.

I read here https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2022-04/css-cascade-layers/ that no-layered styles are more specific than layered styles. Since the recent versions of PrimeNG include it, Tabler style is overriding PrimeNG style.

I've already tried changing the sort order in the `angular.json` file:

```
            ...
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/tabler.min.css",
              "node_modules/@tabler/icons-webfont/tabler-icons.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            ...
```

However, it didn't work.

Is there any way or trick to make @layer more specific?

Comment: You mean make non-!important layered styles override non-!important non-layered styles? No. not right now, although it remains an open issue with the CSS working group. In the meantime. the best strategy is simply not to have unlayered styles. Make sure all your styles are in a layer and then you can control the precedence of the layers as you wish.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, that's not an option because the '@layer' is from the PrimeNG files. Although I can modify and store them in the repo, I rather not do it because it will be a problem when we try to update dependencies. Then, I'm needing to overwrite all what Tabler styles mess up.